# Programmatic auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, autolayout, swift4

So I have a 2d array of UIImageViews which displays a game screen(like a chess board but in various rows/columns)

At the moment I have using the following auto layout code:

```
func setConstraints() {
    for i in 0...rows-1 {
        for j in 0...cols-1 {
                //First image
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                floorImageView[i][j].anchor(top: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 180, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
                cellImageView[i][j].anchor(top: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 180, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
            }
                //Middle rows
            else if (i == 0 && j > 0) {
                floorImageView[i][j].anchor(top: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: floorImageView[i][j-1].trailingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 180, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
                cellImageView[i][j].anchor(top: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: floorImageView[i][j-1].trailingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 180, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
            }
                //First image of every row
            else if (i > 0 && j == 0) {
                floorImageView[i][j].anchor(top: floorImageView[i-1][j].bottomAnchor, leading: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
                cellImageView[i][j].anchor(top: floorImageView[i-1][j].bottomAnchor, leading: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
            }
                //Middle js
            else if (i > 0 && j > 0) {
                floorImageView[i][j].anchor(top: floorImageView[i-1][j].bottomAnchor, leading: floorImageView[i][j-1].trailingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
                cellImageView[i][j].anchor(top: floorImageView[i-1][j].bottomAnchor, leading: floorImageView[i][j-1].trailingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
            }
                //Last row
            else if (i > 0 && j == cols-1) {
                floorImageView[i][j].anchor(top: floorImageView[i-1][j].bottomAnchor, leading: floorImageView[i][j-1].trailingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 200, right: 10), size: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
                cellImageView[i][j].anchor(top: floorImageView[i-1][j].bottomAnchor, leading: floorImageView[i][j-1].trailingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 200, right: 10), size: .init(width: 40, height: 40))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is this:

[image]

But what I really want is that no matter the size of the level it always stay in the centre of the display (iPhone X) Without having part of the level cut off on the sides or leaving big gaps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that the view.anchor() method is an extension made by LetsBuildThatApp and the method itself is pretty self explanatory

Comment: You could really use `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't generally tend to use a lot of pods but [Snapkit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) will really help you solve your problem with a lot cleaner and descriptive code...